# Iframe src tag for internet and intranet

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have an iframe that shows information.
But in my case the content is available from the intranet and must also be available from the internet.
So the problem is the src tag.
Now, to see the site in my intranet I use:

```
$address = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
<iframe src = "http://$address...."></iframe>
```

But obviously, this is NOT visible from the internet because `$address` is not the host name.
If I use the absolute path like "/srv/www/htdocs..." it doesn't work.

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Could you provide more info? By intranet, do you mean that server does not allow connections from the internet? Are the intranet pages and where you run this script served on the same webserver? Are you viewing this script on the local network or from a host not connected to the intranet's server?

Comment: Ye the webserver is the same.
I've tried the other solution listed above, but nothing.
The page cannot load. Is just working in the intranet...

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead of `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`

Answer (score 0):

in case that server is a public available, webserver you could do:

```
<iframe src = "http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

`iframe`s are not magic. You cannot use them to load content that the browser would not be able to load directly -- if the target (intranet) page cannot be loaded directly, then it will not load in an `iframe` either.